# How can I use distinccount for 3 measures?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Below is a table with the information I've calculated so far.

The 3 columns that contain the word "Days late" are measures. I'm trying to count how many unique projects have any of the 3 types of delays. In this case, the correct number is 4 projects.

[image]

I tried using distinctcount, but it's only for columns, and I have measures. I need to solve this using another measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Late Projects =
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Project'[Project number]),
    FILTER('Project', [Days late 1] + [Days late 2] + [Days late 3] > 0)
  )
```